# Visualize $\mathbb E[X_T] = \int_\Omega X_{T(\omega)}(\omega) P(d\omega) $?

Tags: probability

Let $T$ be a stopping time. How to understand what $\mathbb E[X_T] = \int_\Omega X_{T(\omega)}(\omega) P(d\omega)$ is? What are some simple examples?

Comment: Try some hitting and stopping times for the simple symmetric random walk. This is usually where stopping times are encountered first.

Comment: Consider drawing numbers from the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ until their sum exceeds $1$. What's the expected value of the last number drawn?